# Visual Studio crash accessing source control. "some reload or shell operations were canceled"

Tags: visual-studio

"some reload or shell operations were canceled or caused errors"
I've been using Visual Studio for years and 2013 for quite a while.  Within that I have a Source Code control connection to Perforce SCM.  This has been operating for months without problems until today.

Today, after mucking up some WPF design, doing things that may have crashed the designer, I started getting this pop-up message saying there's a problem.  Visual Studio recommends I close the solution and restart, but the problem remains.

Now when I close the solution it doesn't remember what files to reopen next time.  When I edit something, it checks out correctly but pops up the "Some reload or shell operations were canceled...".

The good news is the program still compiles, runs, WPF designers work.  But how can I fix this?

EDIT: I tried deleting files in the directories, and I tried reverting the solution file.  If I had a clue where to look, maybe I could identify what I missed in trying to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a "crash", you get a generic notification that Visual Studio is having trouble working with your Perforce SSC plugin.

Very first thing to do is obtain the latest version of the plugin, version 2014.1.  It uses OpenSSL to talk to the server, the library that's infamous for the [Heartbleed bug](http://heartbleed.com/).  In itself a possible reason for these errors if the Perforce server admin has updated the server.  Do talk to him about this, he might not necessarily want to support the latest version.

Next thing to do is to enable logging so you'll have an idea what exactly is going wrong.  Do keep in mind that the problem might originate at the other end of the wire.  Use Tools > Options > Source Control >SCC Provider and click Advanced.  Turn on the Log All option.  Select Enable logging to file and provide a file name.  When the error reproduces, close your solution and have a look-see at the file.  Talk to your Perforce server admin or give Perforce a call if you see any.

Comment: In the interrim I switched to a 3rd party Perforce plugin, and that seems to work okay for now.  I am my own admin, not running a new server, but I will try what you suggest if the opportunity comes up.  Thank you.